# declare inline style or new class for an element that needs a little correction

Tags: html, css

I've got external stylesheet that defines basic classes. These classes get the job done in majority of the cases. However, sometimes a particular element needs just a little tweak (usually just 1), such as `margin-top:0` instead of `60px` (as defined in class)

It seems ideal to use inline style for this particular case, but I've been told to use external stylesheets.

Is it better performance wise to define a new class with just with only 1 rule ( `margin-top:0` in my case) or set `margin inline?`

I am not concerned about readability, since hand made code is usually pretty succinct.

Example:

html:

```
<section class="section-centered clear-margin"></section>
```

css:

```
.section-centered{
//stuff here
margin:60px;
}
.clear-margin{
margin-top:0
}
```

**VS**

html:

```
<section class="section-centered" style="margin-top:0"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use external styles

Long answer: There is two main issues to address in the **inline** VS **external**

**Preformance**

let's say 10 elements in your html that you added a small correction inline styles to. This would not have any harm to your performance, actually, It could in some cases increase your First-paint. Realistically, small inline changes would not increase the page load. However if you add a block of internal style that's job is solely to draw the skeleton of your app, this would give your users a better understanding of what to expect when the page fully loads.

By only adding small changed like this to an element like a div, you will ease the work needed by the css engine to do the lookup for that particular div. Today, this is really not noticeable.

**Maintainability**

When you add inline styles to your document, you are also adding more work. Theoretically of course. Let's say you have to do some small design changes in five months from now. Instead of inspecting the element, tweaking your changes and updating the css file, you have to also dive in your html file to find the inline styles and update them accordingly. This is one additional step for you to achieve your goal and move on.

It will also add more noise to your markup, making it harder to read and understand in order to do changes.

Here and now, just adding a line of inline css will most likely be the shortest amount of work to achieve your goal. In the long run however, it will bite back.

**Conclution**

As the main issue here is maintainability and is more or less subjective, there is no direct right answer to this question.

Personally, I like to always add styling externally. This makes me more oriented and makes me more easily debug and do changes later on.

Also, instead of creating a new class for just adding 1 style attribute, I would recommend to explore your options before. Most of the time, you can create a combo of selectors to pinpoint your element instead of creating a new class.